# How to fetch TPU utilization details in coral developer board using tflite_runtime or linux command

Tags: google-coral, edge-tpu

I am just trying to fetch the TPU utilization details in coral dev board. But can't find any relevant for the same..!

Please share your findings / suggestions..!

Comment: There are no performance registers to read, so taking benchmarks and timing measurements are your best way to estimate utilization.  Look at the inference times after Figure 6, here: https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#6-run-a-model-using-the-pycoral-api  This shows the difference between the PCIe bus transfer with inference, and just one inference time.   Each model will have a different utilization depending on the number of layers and parameters.  There are public benchmarks you can review: https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/benchmarks/  The models are available to run your own tests.

Comment: @usbguru Thanks for your response.. Though i ve already came across those points..  opened this question to find out still any thing there.. i ve missed..

Comment: This is a good question. I've been looking through the `/sys/class/apex/apex_0`, and there is some stuff about temperatures there. Im yet to find TPU utilization though.